# Spring: does objects privately created in spring managed beans accessible by spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have a Java class which is something like the following:

```
public class Foo{
   public void doSomething(){
     StageA a = new StageA();
     StageB b = new StageB();
     StageC c = new StageC();
     a.execute();
     b.execute();
     c.execute();
   }
}
```

Now, assuming I can't really edit this class itself, could I still use *spring AOP* to apply logging `around` the `execute` methods? (presumably without using *aspect4j*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write an `@Around` advice with `execution` pointcut targeting methods whose name is `execute()` as follows:

```
@Around("execution(* execute(..))")
public Object execute(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable
{
    // Log statements before the call;

    Object obj = pjp.proceed();

    // Log statements after the call;

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: can it work for non spring-managed objects? As far as i know, spring creates a proxy around the beans so it is actually calling the proxy and not the actual objects itself

Comment: It works only for spring managed object. You can qualify your Stage objects with `@Configurable` annotation so that they become spring managed even if you create objects with `new` operator. Then the `@Around` aspect would work on the execute methods.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can log method and it's required time(for performance) but I don't think you would be able to log what method is doing.

From [Spring Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-defn) :

> Around advice: Advice that surrounds a join point such as a method invocation. This is the most powerful kind of advice. Around advice can perform custom behavior before and after the method invocation. It is also responsible for choosing whether to proceed to the join point or to shortcut the advised method execution by returning its own return value or throwing an exception.

If you are using log4j loggers internally in your methods you can log what method is doing by configuring log4j.

> (presumably without using aspect4j)

--> Spring internally uses `aspectJ`

Check [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice) for reference and example

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED:**
I don't think that it is possible to log execution of the each "execute" method in your case without changing Foo or Stage classes. Because Stage... classes are not managed by container. You can only log when your doSomething method will start execution (if Foo class is managed by Spring container), you cannot control it's execution flow.

If your classes are to be managed by Spring container, then you can easy do this. You should simply write Spring AOP "around" aspect for Stage... classes, not for Foo class.

Here is an example of simple logging aspect:

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Order(value=2)
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Around("execution(* com.blablabla.server..*.*(..))")
    public Object logMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
        final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
        Object retVal = null;

        try {
            StringBuffer startMessageStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            startMessageStringBuffer.append("Start method ");
            startMessageStringBuffer.append(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            startMessageStringBuffer.append("(");

            Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                startMessageStringBuffer.append(args[i]).append(",");
            }
            if (args.length > 0) {
                startMessageStringBuffer.deleteCharAt(startMessageStringBuffer.length() - 1);
            }

            startMessageStringBuffer.append(")");

            logger.trace(startMessageStringBuffer.toString());

            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.start();

            retVal = joinPoint.proceed();

            stopWatch.stop();

            StringBuffer endMessageStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            endMessageStringBuffer.append("Finish method ");
            endMessageStringBuffer.append(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            endMessageStringBuffer.append("(..); execution time: ");
            endMessageStringBuffer.append(stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis());
            endMessageStringBuffer.append(" ms;");

            logger.trace(endMessageStringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            StringBuffer errorMessageStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

             // Create error message 
             logger.error(errorMessageStringBuffer.toString(), e)

            throw ex;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: how would i write aspects for the Stage class if they aren't managed by the spring container??

Comment: Sorry, stupid mistake. You cannot write Spring AOP aspect for classes that are not managed by container. And this is your case. I will think another way to do this now.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to log execution of the each "execute" method in your case without changing Foo class. Because Stage... classes are not managed by container. You can only log when your doSomething mwthod will start execution (if Foo class is managed by Spring container), you cannot control it's execution flow.